# AngularJS: Populate a text box with the ID from a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In the following code, the repeated input textbox CountryID is affected selection of the Country text box.  When the page is inspected after a selection, the only visible text box has the value with the correct value, but this value is not displayed on the page.  When the submit button is pressed, the Item.CountryID is blank.  But if the one visible text box is populated manually, Item.CountryID becomes populated. How do I get the required value into the visible text box which already seems to have its value set?

```
<tr><td>Country:</td><td>
<select name="country" class="select" id="country" ng-model="Category.Country" >
<option  ng-repeat="Item in SPCountryListItems  | orderBy:'Country'" id="{{Category.CountryID}}">{{Item.Country}}</option>
</select>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>County ID</td>
<td>                    
<span ng-repeat="Item in SPCountryListItems  | filter:Category.Country">
<input type="text"  ng-model="Category.CountryID" value="{{Item.CountryID}}" id="CountryID" />
</span>
```

From the Inspect window (the value is not visible on the page):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Category.CountryID" value="10" id="CountryID" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
```

Comment: it seems you are using AngularJs to do this, but tag this JQuery? what is your intension, do you want to do this in Angular or JQuery?

Comment: Oops!  Wrong title.  (thanks @devtye)

The bigger picture here is that this is partial code from a SharePoint page. The CountryID is the IndexID from a lookup list. I have to get the CountryID returned in the Category.CountryID